# Xdebug triggering a breakpoint (when I don't want it to) at Composer autoload

Tags: php, composer-php, xdebug

I have a Laravel project set up, which is doing a Composer autoload as normal. The autoloader is mapped with the default from a Laravel install in the composer.json file:

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
    }
```

My problem is when I use Xdebug from within PhpStorm, it triggers a breakpoint when the class gets included via the autoloader, instead of at the line I have put a breakpoint on.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Bases\BaseJsonApiController;
use CloudCreativity\LaravelJsonApi\Contracts\Store\StoreInterface;
use CloudCreativity\LaravelJsonApi\Http\Requests\FetchResource;
use CloudCreativity\LaravelJsonApi\Http\Requests\FetchResources;

/**
 * Class IndexController
 *
 * @package App\Http\Controllers
 */
class IndexController extends BaseJsonApiController
{
    public function index(StoreInterface $store, FetchResources $request)
    {
        $a = 1;
        return parent::index($store, $request);
    }
}
```

I've only added the `$a = 1;` line to test adding breakpoint.

If I put a breakpoint on the `$a = 1;` line, then the first breakpoint I hit is when the Composer autoload includes this file, so it stops at `class IndexController`. If I skip to the next breakpoint it hits the intended line, `$a = 1;`.

The stack trace at the first triggered breakpoint is:

```
IndexController.php:15, include()
ClassLoader.php:444, Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
ClassLoader.php:322, Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
Container.php:803, spl_autoload_call()
Container.php:803, ReflectionClass->__construct()
Container.php:803, Illuminate\Foundation\Application->build()
Container.php:681, Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve()
Container.php:629, Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
Application.php:768, Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make()
Route.php:233, Illuminate\Routing\Route->getController()
Route.php:833, Illuminate\Routing\Route->controllerMiddleware()
Route.php:794, Illuminate\Routing\Route->gatherMiddleware()
Router.php:693, Illuminate\Routing\Router->gatherRouteMiddleware()
Router.php:673, Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack()
Router.php:657, Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRoute()
Router.php:623, Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute()
Router.php:612, Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch()
Kernel.php:176, App\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure:/var/www/open-banking-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:173-177}()
Pipeline.php:130, Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure:/var/www/open-banking-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:128-136}()
InjectDebugbar.php:65, Barryvdh\Debugbar\Middleware\InjectDebugbar->handle()
Pipeline.php:171, Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure:/var/www/open-banking-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:147-180}()
TransformsRequest.php:21, Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull->handle()
Pipeline.php:171, Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure:/var/www/open-banking-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:147-180}()
TransformsRequest.php:21, App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings->handle()
Pipeline.php:171, Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure:/var/www/open-banking-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:147-180}()
ValidatePostSize.php:27, Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle()
Pipeline.php:171, Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure:/var/www/open-banking-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:147-180}()
CheckForMaintenanceMode.php:62, App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle()
Pipeline.php:171, Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure:/var/www/open-banking-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:147-180}()
TrustProxies.php:57, App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies->handle()
Pipeline.php:171, Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure:/var/www/open-banking-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php:147-180}()
Pipeline.php:105, Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->then()
Kernel.php:151, App\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter()
Kernel.php:116, App\Http\Kernel->handle()
index.php:55, {main}()
```

I guess the workaround at the moment is to skip the first breakpoint, but I'd be interested to find out why its happening and how to stop it doing that.

---- Edit

custom php.ini settings for xdebug:

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=docker.for.mac.localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

Comment: Could it be that includeFile fails?

Comment: 1) Does it behaves the same in another project? 2) `ClassLoader.php:444, Composer\Autoload\includeFile()` That is an unusual place to break... Must be specific to your setup I guess. What's your Xdebug settings (from php.ini; actual from phpinfo() output; in PhpStorm). 3) What does xdebug log has to say about such debug session

Comment: @PavelLint the includeFile works when Xdebug isn't on, so I don't think it'll be that.

Comment: @LazyOne It behaves the same in all my projects, although they've been set up in a similar way. I'm installing Xdebug on a docker image and connecting through that.

I've added xdebug.ini config in my edit above.

Comment: Are you certain it is not a stored breakpoint in your IDE that's possibly not showing the breakpoint icon in the file(s)? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-breakpoints.html

Comment: @seantunwin its not that. The only breakpoint I've set is on the `$a = 1;` line. I've checked that through using the "View Breakpoints" button in PhpStorm

Comment: I imagine you never got around this, right? I'm having a very similar issue, where Xdebug will stop _before_ the breakpoint. Either at class definition or method definition... Trying to find a way to use this info for your question, but it's not easy. Not sure this is actually composer related...

Comment: @yivi Nope, not been able to figure out a solution yet.

Comment: 1) Maybe it's some kind of "method breakpoint" (but then it would have a diff icon and will be placed on a method line); 2) In theory could be related to OPCache settings (comments handling)... 3) Still, Xdebug log may provide some insights.

Comment: @LazyOne xdebug log - https://gist.github.com/nickedwards/88819fe7627012ea7b1654daefb89e94

Looks like it thinks there's a breakpoint at that line. There definitely isn't. The only breakpoint I've set was on line 19. Its breaking at line 15, then line 19 after that.

Comment: 1) IDE clearly sets breakpoint at line #19 only ... but Xdebug somehow resolves "another" breakpoints at #15 (notice the `<notify` node with `"breakpoint_resolved"` name -- available since Xdebug 2.8 only). Can you try Downgrading Xdebug to 2.7.x for the moment? 2) Can you still show the actual file for that controller (as is, without editing anything)? At least those top 20 lines.

Comment: On related note -- a PhpStorm ticket with similar issue. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-49832 TBH, right now for me it looks like Xdebug issue as I do not see anything obviously wrong in Xdebug log from IDE side.

Comment: @LazyOne I've updated the original post to include the full file. It was mostly just some comments I'd taken out. I'll try downgrade to 2.7 shortly and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for the file. I assume it has not been edited (no extra lines removed; I do not care about actual class names/comment text editing -- just the overall it stays the same). The comment takes 5 lines but that "magic breakpoint" is resolved to class declaration line .. which is only 4 lines difference. Based on the above it should not be the OPCache settings then (`opcache.save_comments=0` can remove comments from cached file which *possibly* may case different line numbers). BTW -- any symlinks in the path?

Comment: @LazyOne Nah, there's no other lines in the file. I wanted to create a simple version of the class to test out the breakpoint issues, and this is it.

No symlinks either, they're all actual files, although the whole directory is getting mounted as a volume in the docker image for development, if that makes a difference?

I'm just about to downgrade xdebug, been a busy morning.

Comment: @LazyOne Downgrading to 2.7.2 makes it work correctly. Must be a problem in 2.8